# Contacts with categories : groups,favourites and Alphabets

Tags: android, material-design

I am doing contacts with categories : groups,favourites and Alpahabets.So far I had found one [sample](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ListViewVariants).But there is no favourites and groups.If I get any sample link relevant to the below Uploaded image that will be helpful for me.

Contact Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the  [link](http://codetheory.in/android-dividing-listview-sections-group-headers/) which solved my issue.